# Preserve memoir headings for 1 page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir

The default behavior of the `memoir` package is to change the headings immediately upon sectioning. This is counterintuitive to me, as I think the headings are to remind the reader of the section they are currently reading. This is not necessary when a new section begins, as the section header does that for them. The reader still needs a reminder as to which section they are *finishing* rather than which they are starting.

How can I change that behavior so the headers are updated on the *next* page after a section command, rather than the actual page of the section command?

If you run the MWE I provide below, look at pages 2–4.
I want the following headers:

- page 2: the heading is as I want it
- page 3: I want the heading to match that of page 2
- page 4: the heading is as I want it

  Can I do this within `memoir`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[17pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\copypagestyle{MWE}{headings}
\makepsmarks{MWE}{%
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{Chapter\ }{:\ }}
\makeoddhead{MWE}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}
\makeoddfoot{MWE}{}{\thepage}{}
\pagestyle{MWE}


\begin{document}
\chapter{The MWE}
    \section{Introduction}
        \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{History of the MWE}
        \lipsum[6-10]
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each mark there are three variables set by TeX: `\botmark`, `\firstmark` and `\topmark`.

While `\leftmark` uses `\botmark` (the last set mark on the current page) `\rightmark` uses `\firstmark` (the first set mark on the current page).

But you want to use the `\topmark` which is the last mark of the previous page.

Based on the definition of `\rightmark` in `latex.ltx`

```
\let\@rightmark\@secondoftwo
...
\def\rightmark{\expandafter\@rightmark\firstmark\@empty\@empty}
```

you can define

```
\providecommand*{\righttopmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\topmark\@empty\@empty}
```

and then use `\righttopmark` instead of `\rightmark`:

```
\documentclass[17pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\righttopmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\topmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother
\copypagestyle{MWE}{headings}
\makepsmarks{MWE}{%
  \nouppercaseheads
  \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{Chapter\ }{:\ }}
\makeoddhead{MWE}{\leftmark}{}{\righttopmark}
\makeoddfoot{MWE}{}{\thepage}{}
\pagestyle{MWE}


\begin{document}
\chapter{The MWE}
  \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-5]
  \section{History of the MWE}
    \lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]